# DevExpress eXpressApp Framework (XAF) - Extension property with drop-down list

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, xaf

I'm trying to add an extension property to the model column that allows to select value from the drop-down list. So when I open Model Editor and choose some column in ListView I will be able to select value from the list for this extension property.

I have created interface for property and registered it.

```
public interface IModelExDatabaseColumn : IModelColumn
{
   [Category("Data")]
   [Required]
   string DatabaseColumn { get; set; }
}

public override void ExtendModelInterfaces(ModelInterfaceExtenders extenders)
{
   base.ExtendModelInterfaces(extenders);
   extenders.Add<IModelColumn, IModelExDatabaseColumn>();
}
```

Now it is visible in properties. How can I add drop-down list to it with some string values which generates in code?

Comment: Your question has been answered at http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q354062 P.S. In the future, I suggest you use the [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) to get official and guaranteed assistance on the use of DevExpress products. Note that FULL SUPPORT IS FREE during the evaluation period (30 days).

Comment: Actually, that question is mine too :) But from Stack Overflow I always wait the best answers, not so awful like in support...

Comment: >>not so awful like in support
Actually, that answer is mine too;-)
All best answers about DevExpress products are in one place - Support Center.

Comment: I guessed that its you by the names. Sorry for direct speaking about support quality, but its really difficult to understand something from the code fragment (that can't be compiled and also uses unknown functions) when you are very new to technology.

Comment: I think I should apologize for the inconvenience too, because my initial assumption was not quite correct. Literally, I thought the following: "Since this guy started implementing his own model extension, he should be already good enough to the XAF technology:-) Hence, I assummed that a small piece of code would be sufficient for you to crack this small nut;-)